# Save image fetched from server in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, unityscript

I get an image from my server and I set it as a texture to a Gameobject. But what I also want to do is to save it in my project as a png. Any idea how am I supposed to do that ? I am new to unity.

Here is how I fetch my image and set it as a texture:

```
WWW wB = new WWW ("http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx");
yield return wB;
cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = wB.texture;
```

I would like to save wb.Texture as a png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void SaveTextureToFile(Texture2D texture, string fileName)
{
    var bytes=texture.EncodeToPNG();
    var file = new File.Open(Application.dataPath + "/"+fileName, FileMode.Create);
    var binary= new BinaryWriter(file);
    binary.Write(bytes);
    file.Close();
}

SaveTextureToFile(wB.texture, "abc.png");
```

Note that [Application.dataPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) can be replaced with [Application.persistentDataPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
WWW wB = new WWW ("http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx");
yield return wB;
byte[] bytes = wb.Texture.EncodeToPNG();
```

Now u could save bytes into a png file in your desired path.